# nested hashset of lists?

Tags: c#, list, nested, hashset

I'm working on one of the project Euler problems, and I wanted to take the approach of creating a list of values, and adding the list to a Hashset, this way I could evaluate in constant time if the list already exists in the hashset, with the end goal to count the number of lists in the hashset for my end result.

The problem I'm having is when I create a list in this manner.

```
HashSet<List<int>> finalList = new HashSet<List<int>>();
List<int> candidate = new List<int>();
candidate.Add(5);
finalList.Add(candidate);

if (finalList.Contains(candidate) == false) finalList.Add(candidate);
candidate.Clear();

//try next value
```

Obviously the `finalList[0]` item is cleared when I clear the candidate and is not giving me the desired result. Is it possible to have a hashset of lists(of integers) like this? How would I ensure a new list is instantiated each time and added as a new item to the hashset, perhaps say in a for loop testing many values and possible list combinations?

Comment: Are you expecting `candidate[0]` to be the key? It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a value which is unique for each list as a key or identifier? You could create a HashSet for your keys which will unlock your lists.

Comment: If I sorted the list could I create a hash value of the list and add the created hash to the end-result list? The goal is to count the number of lists that I've created that are unique. For instance, (first candidate)list = [0] = 2, [1] = 6, [2] = 7 and hash this list of items to say for example 000110, and add this hash to a list or hashset. Thus the next time 2,6,7 showed up in a list, it would already contain the result hash. Not sure if I'm making any sense :)

Comment: I understood your problem from the start. My point was that you can generate a unique key for each of your list, like a key of '000110' in your upgraded sorted model. These keys should be in your HashSet and they should unlock the lists corresponding to them somehow (I can imagine many solutions to this). So, when you "add" a new list to the HashSet you validate it first, by generating its unique key. If the key can be found in the HashSet, then the list cannot be added, because it already exists in your HashSet.

Comment: Apologies, someone said I was unclear so I didn't know if I explained it well enough. Okay I will start heading in this direction then once I find a way to generate a unique key and add it to the hashset.

Comment: No problems, I was just trying to clarify my idea. I am glad it helped you and I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary instead. The only thing is you have to test to see if the Dictionary already has the list. This is easy to do, by creating a simple class that supports this need.

```
class TheSimpleListManager
{
    private Dictionary<String, List<Int32>> Lists = new Dictionary<String, List<Int32>>();

    public void AddList(String key, List<Int32> list)
    {
       if(!Lists.ContainsKey(key))
       {
           Lists.Add(key, list);
       }
       else
       {
          // list already exists....
       }
    }
}
```

This is just a quick sample of an approach.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your `clear` issue: Since its an object reference, you would have to create a `new List` and add it to the `HashSet`.
You can create the new List by passing the old one into its constructor.

```
        HashSet<List<int>> finalList = new HashSet<List<int>>();
        List<int> candidate = new List<int>();

        candidate.Add(5);

        var newList = new List<int>(candidate);
        finalList.Add(newList);

        if (finalList.Contains(newList) == false) //Not required for HashSet
            finalList.Add(newList);

        candidate.Clear();
```

***NOTE***: `HashSet` internally does a  `contains` before adding items. In otherwords, here even if you execute `finalList.Add(newList);` `n` times, it would add `newList` only once. Therefore it is not necessary to do a contains check.